# Linear regression model up to nth power of number

Tags: r, syntax, linear-regression, glm, lm

I know, that when I'm using [lm()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) or [glm()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html) function to fit the regression model in R, it's possible to write interactions up to n-th degree like this:

```
fit <- glm(formula=outVar ~ (inVar1 + inVar2 + inVar3)^n,
           data=d)
```

But is it possible to do similar thing with the power of variables, so I don't have to specify `I(inVar1^2)`, `I(inVar1^3)` and to exclude interactions between different powers of the same variable?

---

#### EDIT

I'd like to do something like this:

```
formula=outVar ~ (poly(inVar1 + inVar2 + inVar3, 2))^2
```

So I'd get the formula

```
outVar ~ inVar1 + inVar2 + inVar3 + I(inVar1^2) + I(inVar2^2) + I(inVar3^2) + inVar1:inVar2 + inVar1:inVar3 + inVar2:inVar3 + I(inVar1^2):I(inVar2^2) + I(inVar1^2):I(inVar3^2) + I(inVar1^2):I(inVar3^2) + inVar1:I(inVar2^2) + inVar1:I(inVar3^2)...
```

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi Could you, please, provide an example with conflicting interactions (e.g. `I(inVar1^2):I(inVar1^3)`) excluded?

Comment: @Eenoku, it could be helpful to write the expected long form out in the question (i.e. all terms you want to include), then people can suggest shorter ways of writing it.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1061/formula/29295/create-linear-quadratic-and-second-order-interaction-terms#t=201703210915463399866

Comment: @Axeman Example added into the question

Comment: `as.formula(paste('y ~', paste0('poly(', variable_names, ', n)')))` might be the easiest